# Sending push notification using GCM in PHP

Tags: php

I am using a following code to send push notification messages using GCM in PHP but I cannott get it working. I tried this:

```
/*------send_messages_gcm--------*/  
    private function send_messages_gcm(){
        global $wpdb;
        include_once './config.php';

      $GOOGLE_API_KEY= "AIzaSyD-8NPnZ3WpdMIc-9TtKPCMRQtcliykc-s";
$registatoin_ids=$_REQUEST['rj_id'];

        $message="hii anita";
         // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );
       // print_r($fields);
         $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' .$GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;

    }
```

When I run this function then it produces this result:

> registration_ids" field is not a JSON array

I also tried `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode());` instead of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields))`, but it doesn't worked.

Comment: and what r u getting in `var_dump($_REQUEST['rj_id'])`? or `var_dump($fields)`?

Comment: HI this might can help you http://mitalichokshi.blogspot.in/ and http://mitalichokshi.blogspot.in/2015/05/how-to-send-bulk-push-notifications-to.html

Comment: i am getting a device id from var_dump($_REQUEST['rj_id']) and fields give a push notification message

Answer (score 0):

due to sending a message to multiple receivers:

```
registration_ids" field must be a JSON array
```

so

```
$registatoin_ids = array($_REQUEST['rj_id']);
```